# Joomla Form - Retrieve Values based on ID (Front End)

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform, jtable

I'm using jform and joomla's core features of dealing with forms. i.e. Using XML as forms then storing it with JTable etc.

My custom component has to deal with CRUD operation strictly at front-end. Hence, insert, select, update queries should work at front-end only.

I'm able to insert form data (with jform and jtable) successfully. Now the time has arrived, where I need to retrieve existing form data which was inserted earlier by user.

Following is my tasks which inserts data:

```
index.php?option=com_helpdesk&task=request.add
```

My controller extends, JControllerForm base class.

My question is, how can I retrieve data in if I pass "id" parameter to following URL:

```
index.php?option=com_helpesk&task=request.edit&id=1
```

When I see usual code from core classes, I saw, they have extended JModelAdmin class in Administrator part. I never seen code which retrieves values from database and show it on form. Do I really need to extend my model with JModelAdmin class?

Can someone route me to the correct path here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any issue extending `JModelAdmin` class. I do it myself in development and furthermore you can extend you classes which were made for administrator part. You can see it in action in `com_content` [form model](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_content/models/form.php):

```
// Base this model on the backend version.
require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content/models/article.php';

class ContentModelForm extends ContentModelArticle
```